# Maatwebsite/Excel 3.1 laravel 9

Tags: php, laravel-9, maatwebsite-excel

While using Maatwebsite/excel 3.1 for downloading the excel with data such as excel sheet with headings and using data from AD it is just downloading blanksheet

In the previous version 2.1 we had Excel::create function working properly. now we migrated to laravel 9, I am using 3.1v so it has been replaced by Excel::download function. but the data is not getting populated in the excel